# run different command in the loop based on the item attributes in ansible

Tags: ansible

here I got an issue that I need run a command based on an list of items, like the following code:

```
- name: Task command
  command: "command1 keyword1 --param1 {{ item.attribute1 }}" 
  with_items:
    - "{{ list_of_items }}"
```

but now, I need to update the playbook to add more features, such as when `item.attribute1 == 'a'`, still run the above command, but otherwise, the command should be something like this

```
command: "command1 keyword2 --param2 {{ item.attribute1 }}"  # completely different from the above command!
```

is there a way in ansible to support this kind of syntax that support running different command when use the loop?

Appreciate to the help of any kinds.

Comment: Aside from your question, you should always can store complete commands in your list

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski thanks for your command, but the command I am inputing here is way too long more than 20 params to put it as an attribute of the list item, and it will create a lot of duplicate stuff in the list as well. But thanks for providing this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what are you looking for?

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    commands:
      a: 'command1 keyword1 --param1'
      b: 'command1 keyword2 --param2'
      c: 'command1 keyword3 --param3'
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ commands[item.attribute1] + ' ' + item.attribute1 }}"
      loop:
        - {attribute1: 'a'}
        - {attribute1: 'b'}
        - {attribute1: 'c'}
```

gives

```
"msg": "command1 keyword1 --param1 a"
"msg": "command1 keyword2 --param2 b"
"msg": "command1 keyword3 --param3 c"
```